# how to get username and domain of windows logged in client using python code?

Tags: django, python-2.7

when user logs in to his desktop windows os authenticates him against Active Directory Server.
so Whenever he accesses a web page  he should not be thrown a login page for entering his userid or password.Instead, his userid and domain  need to be captured from his desktop and passed to the web server.(let him enter password after that)

Is this possible in python to get username and domain of of client?
win32api.GetUserName() gives the username of the server side.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... what you probably want to do is use Django's RemoteUserMiddleware and leave user authentication to the Web Server which can then be configured to handle it. The solution from [Ntlm/Kerberos authentication in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401512/ntlm-kerberos-authentication-in-django) should work, but as mentioned it's a bit quirky - not all browsers support it correctly, and you have to modify browser settings for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called Single sign on (SSO) and it's much easier to implement on actual web server than Django.

So, you should check how to do SSO on Apache/Nginx/whateverYouAreUsing, then the web server will forward the authenticated username to your django app.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a javascript question to me. I think you'll have to add javascript to your login page that attempts to access the details and returns them to the server.

I would have thought that there would be security measures to prevent this, however this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968690/get-windows-username-with-javascript) suggests others have managed something similar.

UPDATE

It looks like there might be some useful information [in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/auth-remote-user/)

Comment: thank you but its not working for me..  there is no other way other than javascript ?